# Keep kernel running for execution of scheduled task

Tags: kernel, command-line, scheduling

How can I keep a kernel running until all scheduled tasks have completed? For example upon running the following script `bazinga.m`:

```
RunScheduledTask[Print["Bazinga!"], {5, 10}]
```

with

```
$ math -script bazinga.m
```

the kernel immediately exits and does not run the scheduled task at all. Setting `$IgnoreEOF` to `True` does not make a difference.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "all scheduled tasks have completed"?  Do you mean that all repetition of scheduled tasks have completed (and all tasks are set to have a finite number of repetitions---the default is infinite)?  Or do you mean that if a given repetition of a scheduled task is being executed right now, the kernel shouldn't exit until the current repetition finishes?

Comment: In example the kernel should quit after the scheduled task has been executed ten times.

Comment: this issue should be raised with wolfram support.  At the very least the behavior should be documented.

Comment: I have a ticket in with support for something that might be related: If you launch Mathematica 10 from Task Scheduler in Windows 7 x64 (with the "run whether user logged in or not" enabled), the front end launches in the background along with the two kernels, but one immediately dies. In v9 the front end and both kernels stay running, so if you pass a notebook as an argument in Windows Task Scheduler then in 9 it runs in 10 it doesn't. I'll report back when I hear back from support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to check for running [scheduled tasks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScheduledTasks.html), but I am not sure, if the *blocking* behaviour of [`Pause`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pause.html?q=Pause&lang=en) is the best thing to do.

```
RunScheduledTask[Print["Bazinga!"], {5, 10}]
(* a lot of code *)
(* till the end of script *)
While[ Or@@ScheduledTasks[][[All, 5]], Print[DateString[]]; Pause[1]]
```

Output:

```
C:\Software\Dev>math -script test.m
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:14:15"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:14:16"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:14:17"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:14:18"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:14:19"
"Bazinga!"
...
"Bazinga!"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:15:00"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:15:01"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:15:02"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:15:03"
"Wed 18 Jun 2014 21:15:04"
"Bazinga!"
C:\Software\Dev>
```

**Edit:** Changed the index of "Running" boolean from -1 to 5. See the [answer by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51085/2036).

**Edit:** Added the comments in the code sample to stress on the opportunity of doing stuff while the scheduler is running and now checking if ALL schedulers are done like is done in [answer by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51085/2036).

Comment: nice workaround, but it seems to me if you need to do a `While[..,Pause[]]` to check for the tasks you may as well not use the scheduler and just execute the code in the loop..

Comment: I don't agree. You can do a lot of other stuff while the scheduler runs, can't you? And the while loop in the end of the script avoids it from quitting, when other things but the scheduler are done.

Comment: fair enough, i was thinking in terms of the example where the only thing in the script is the `RunScheduledTask`.  The schedule task approach also likely has an advantage if you need precise timing.

Answer (score 7):

A better way to check if any scheduled tasks are active is

```
Or @@ ScheduledTaskActiveQ /@ ScheduledTasks[]
```

The reason why this is better is that it uses an API, thus it is more likely to be robust against future changes in the structure of `ScheduledTaskObject`.  In the Raspberry Pi version current as of 2014-06-18, `ScheduledTaskObject` includes extra options at the end so `[[-1]]` won't work for checking if a task is active (`[[5]]` will though).

Warning: `ScheduledTaskActiveQ[]`, called without arguments, will crash the kernel.  `ScheduledTaskActiveQ` is a public `` System` `` context symbol, but it does not seem to be documented.

Comment: Upvote for an API way. But I am not convinced, that undocumented function is more stable than fixing the index to 5. Also note, that ScheduledTaskActiveQ seems to be new in v9.

Comment: @Johu A ``System` `` context function is quite likely to stay stable long term, even if the documentation page happens to be missing.  Also, if years from now it does break, and I'd need to look at it and fix it, it would be immediately obvious what `ScheduledTaskActiveQ` means while the meaning of `[[5]]` is a bit opaque without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Pause is that it eats cpu resources when in small systems like the raspberry pi. In this case, Pause needs 6% of the cpu. I think that thats a lot for just waiting. So my workaround for that, was to launch wolfram using the -run option:

```
$math -run 'Get["pathToScript"]'
```

Then you can write another scheduled task that exits mathematica when the first task is done. or maybe a counter that exits after the scheduled task finishes the repetitions:

```
ii=10;i=1;
RunScheduledTask[
  Print["Bazinga!"];

  If[i==ii, Exit[],i = i+1];

  , {5, ii}]
```