# Keep batch-mode kernel alive

Tags: kernel

I made a small HTTP server using jlink that works when running with the frontend. Now **I need to keep a stand-alone math kernel alive after all functions have evaluated** for the server to stay up. All functions (including the function to start the server) return immediately, so the behavior of `math -script server.m` is to exit immediately.

Adding `While[True, Pause[1]]` to the end of the file causes the server to become unresponsive. `$IgnoreEOF=True` has no effect (as the documentation says). I experimented briefly with shell tricks (piping to stdin), but did not find a solution -- I'm not a shell expert, and this is on Windows, so solutions are limited to those compatible with PowerShell and [SUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX).

Similar question to [Keep kernel running for execution of scheduled task](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51080/keep-kernel-running-for-execution-of-scheduled-task), but those answers (at least, the `While[True...]` thing) haven't worked.

Comment: Launch the kernel as a slave from Java. See the sample program [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html#9741)

Comment: @mfvonh if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. I did that and it appears to be the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41742/7167)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to launch the kernel as a slave from Java. The standard way is to use these args

```
java ... className -linkmode launch -linkname (* path to kernel *)
```

And in your class:

```
KernelLink ml = null;

try {
  ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(argv);
} catch (MathLinkException e) {
  ...
}
```