# How to check if and when a ScheduledTask is scheduled?

Tags: scheduling

Apparently, on Mathematica

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"
> ```

the functions `ScheduledTaskActiveQ` and `NextScheduledTaskTime` are not working as expected:

```
task = CreateScheduledTask[Print["Bazinga!"], {2}]
RunScheduledTask[task]
ScheduledTaskActiveQ@task
NextScheduledTaskTime@task
RemoveScheduledTask[task]
```

They stay unevaluated and are colored in red in a notebook interface.

It's a bug? Any workaround?

If not a bug, how to check if and when a `ScheduledTask` is scheduled?

Comment: "The object obj can be a `CloudObject` containing a `ScheduledTask` expression or `DocumentGenerator`." - so it's not meant for desktop mma.

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51085/16267